# End the program itself when there is no movement Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Turn off when the programa is not touched for 5-10 minutes.
I am using timer
Even when the program is touched, it closes when the time is up
How can i solve it?

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(300000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener, false, 0, true);
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
fscommand("quit");
}
myTimer.start();
```

Comment: Show what you have attempted. We cannot fix what we cannot see.

Comment: I added the code I used

Comment: You create a timer but where do you reset the timer on some other event like your "touched" whatever that means to you?

Comment: Yeah . I do not want the program to close if someone is working in the program.

Comment: `myTimer.reset();`

reset it and then start it again 

`myTimer.start();` you just have to put that in some event handler that indicates "activity" - perhaps every n time to keep it from firing a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example to study...

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(300000);

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener, false, 0, true);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, reset_Timer); //check for any mouse movement

myTimer.start();

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent) :void
{
    //# function happens when Timer amount is reached (eg: mouse did not move to reset it)

    //choose one below..

    //fscommand("quit"); //# close app

    //myTimer.stop(); myTimer.start(); //# stop and then restart Timer

    //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, reset_Timer); //# cancel any further usage of this function
}

function reset_Timer (e:MouseEvent) :void 
{
    //# function happens after mouse not moved for total millisecond count of Timer amount

    myTimer.reset(); //reset countdown because mouse was moved 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
 How to .start() again when the mouse is not in move ?.

Answer (score 1):

`myTimer.reset();` reset it and then start it again `myTimer.start();` you just have to put that in some event handler that indicates "activity" - perhaps every n time to keep it from firing a lot

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(300000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener, false, 0, true);
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
    fscommand("quit");
}
myTimer.start();
```

I won't dive into the custom event class but there are a good number of sources for that but basically use the `.reset()` and `.start()` in those.

For example

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/12230
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23559690/125981